# How to reflect the changes done in extjsapplication View without re-loading the page?

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I am using chromer debugging i can change the code inside the javascript file to test the changes at run time without reloading the page. but this works only for code written in controller for extJs application. All the code changes done in view file does not reflect.

Anyone know how i can achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: view is already rendered in your browser so you can't change the view , Possible way to reload the page or updateLayout the component

Comment: I would agree with Surya.. View once rendered needs to be re rendered. In case of controller thats not the case.

Comment: Thanks @SuryaPrakashTumma. What you mentioned that i know already. I just want to know like the DOM manipulation in chrome debugger is there a way to do the same for extjs views.

Comment: If you really need to do so - you can do the same DOM manipulations using ExtJS code http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @pagep. But my question remains the same I want to change the dom by code, without reloading the page.